# Visual Studio Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

My computer has Windows 7, 32-bit installed
I have a problem: When you start Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 or 2012 and then click on the toolbox, the tools appear colored and grayed out as if they are inactive. I cant use tools. When you click on any tool from the toolbox, nothing will change as if it was inactive.
Is there a solution to this problem ?

I installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 or 2012 and nothing changed and the same problem remained

Comment: If you can help it, don't use Windows 7. It is really unsafe. Upgrading may also already fix your problem.

Comment: When ToolBox items are grayed out there may be something like a Visual Studio extension causing this to happen. Try starting Visual Studio from the developer command prompt with /Safemode and if that does not work try starting Visual Studio from the developer command prompt with /Log. The log file should be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-the-activity-log?view=vs-2022#to-examine-the-activity-log) and look for errors. Unsure about your version of VS but newer versions may have several log files.

Comment: Note that VS2012 support is over as of Jan 10,2023 so if an error is located in the activity log mentioned in my first reply Microsoft may not assist you. If possible, upgrade your OS as recommended by Fildor and use Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Tools are normally disabled.  They don’t become active until you open a designer.